# How to mask a decimal input using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, jquery-inputmask

I have previously used Telerik's **RadNumericTextBox** for giving input of decimals like below:

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtNewAmt" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
           Width="100px" CssClass="input" Type="Number" EnabledStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
           PlacesBeforeDecimal="11" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="2">
      <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="validateRegExMaskNumeric" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Here, in the input,

1. Only numbers are allowed.
2. Numbers will be aligned from right.
3. Places before decimal can be 11 or less and after decimal can be 2 or less.

But, i don't want to use Telerik anymore.

How to mask the same thing using `Jquery`? Can it be handled using `asp:Textbox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to choose between **[jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)** and **[MaskInput](https://github.com/Mavrin/maskInput)** Plugin. jQuery Mask Plguin is bulkier than MaskInput as it contains more features. But, for my need, i chose MaskInput Plugin.

**You can find some examples [here](http://mavrin.github.io/maskInput/) and my experience [here](https://medium.com/@setu677/how-to-mask-input-fields-in-jquery-93ad00266155).**

Answer (score -1):

try with this code below

Textbox: <input id="txtQty" type="text" />

Jquery

```
$(function () {
$("input[id*='txtQty']").keydown(function (event) {


    if (event.shiftKey == true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || 
        (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || 
        event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 ||
        event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190) {

    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 190)
        event.preventDefault(); 
    //if a decimal has been added, disable the "."-button

});
```

});​